# Is there an elegant way to instantiate a boost::array from a std::vector?

Tags: c++, boost, stdvector, c++03, stdarray

Writing an interface, I have to convert  instances of `std::vector<double>` to `boost::array<double,N>`. Each time, by construction (without bug), I'm sure the vector has the right size.

Here is an example of what I'm currently doing (I have about 100 such functions to write in the interface) :

```
double foo1(const std::vector<double>& x)
{
  assert(x.size() == 4);
  boost::array<double,4> x_;
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    x_[i] = x[i];
  return foo1_(x_);
}

double foo2(const std::vector<double>& x)
{
  assert(x.size() == 6);
  boost::array<double,6> x_;
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    x_[i] = x[i];
  return foo2_(x_);
}
```

**Is there a shorter way to do that ?**

*Note 1: I don't use C++11 for compatibility reasons.*

*Note 2: I added tag `stdarray` because it can maybe help even if it's a C++11 tag.*

Comment: If you always use POD using `memcpy` would be shorter and most probably more efficient. Anyways write a template function once

Comment: @Slava: efficiency doesn't matter in my case. Actually, this is a simplified example. There is small differences in each function, use a general template could be very difficult and unclear to write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something [like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AvoOBmf7yg5s8OMm):

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template<size_t Size, class Container>
boost::array<typename Container::value_type, Size> as_array(const Container &cont)
{
    assert(cont.size() == Size);
    boost::array<typename Container::value_type, Size> result;
    boost::range::copy(cont, result.begin());
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // this is C++11 initialization, but the rest of code is C++03-complient
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    boost::array<int, 3> a = as_array<3>(v);
    boost::range::copy(a, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,", "));
}
```

But keep in mind that such a "translation" from a run-time to a compile-time container might be quite dangerous, as its correctness relies on `assert`, which is eliminated in release mode.

Comment: Nice generic idea ! Concerning the `assert`, we ensure reliability by a large collection of unit-tests in Debug mode. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Write a template function:

```
template<class T,size_t N>
std::array<T,N> convert( const std::vector<T> & v )
{
    //assert(v.size() == N);
    std::array<T,N> r;
    std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), r.begin() );
    return r;
}
```

then your functions will become one liners:

```
double foo1(const std::vector<double>& x)
{
    return foo1_( convert<double,4>( x ) );
}
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/d085sm)

Answer (score 2):

You can template over the number of elements (That's what `array<>` is doing too). If you order the parameters sensibly, you can specify just the size and have `double` still deduced

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T>
boost::array<T, N> from_vector(const std::vector<T> & vec)
{
    assert(x.size() == N);
    boost::array<T, N> res;
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), res.begin());
    return res;
}
```

Which gets used

```
double foo1(const std::vector<double> & vec)
{
    return foo1_(from_vector<4>(vec));
}

double foo2(const std::vector<double> & vec)
{
    return foo2_(from_vector<6>(vec));
}
```

But a better idea would be to re-implement `foo1_` and `foo2_` in terms of iterators (or something like [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL)). You can `assert(std::distance(begin, end) == 4)` as needed

Comment: `foo1_` and `foo2_` are in a library I use.